# Infinite Hirsch length

Tags: gr.group-theory

Can a residually finite group $G \in LFin \rtimes VPoly$ ($G$ is a semi-direct product of a locally finite group by a virtually polycyclic group) have an infinite Hirsch length?

Comment: Please provide a definition for Hirsch length (as is usually given only for virtually polycyclic groups).

Comment: You can use transfinite induction to extend the notion of Hirsch
length to elementary amenable groups (see for example secion 1.5 in Four-Manifolds, Geometries and Knots by Hillman).

Comment: Please give a definition. With transfinite induction I can certainly produce several non-equivalent definitions.

Comment: For instance, following Definition I.5 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.1084v3.pdf, it is trivial that (locally-finite)-by-polycyclic-by-finite implies (finite Hirsch length). But there are other possible definitions: a possible definition for finite Hirsch length is that for every ascending or descending chain of subgroups $(H_n)$, eventually $H_n$ has finite index in (or over) $H_{n+1}$. A non-equivalent variant is to assume the same, but only for normal subgroups $H_n$.

Comment: ... finally Hillman's book is here http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212142v2.pdf... and Theorem 1.8(4) (which just follows the definition) says that $h$ is additive under extensions, and (3) says that $h(N)=0$ for locally finite $N$ (since it's by definition 0 for finite groups). So it is clear that $h$ is finite for (locally finite)-by-(virtually polycyclic) groups. This is not of research level.